# Symbolic link SublimeText3 build systems issue (Mac to PC)

Tags: node.js, build, sublimetext3, symlink

Is there a way to either not link the build systems since they won't work cross platform (but let symlink manage everything else), or tell Sublime to 'ignore' a build system with a certain name, so I can create the PC version and not have the linked mac version break the build?

For example, I have a nodeJS build system and a chrome build (for quick launch to browser), but obviously the paths are different between a Mac and PC, and when symlink does it's magic to my PC, the build systems for each are busted.

Also I wanted to add - I am trying to keep the builds dynamically selected (via selector), so I don't want a solution that recommends just creating my windows-specific builds and manually selecting them!  Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of hours slogging around the interwebs ... it appears sublime build systems take an optional object that will specify what platform to execute the code on.

the notation is as follows (modified if your respective paths are different):

```
 {  
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/node", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.js",

    "windows": // this section executes the below only if the OS is windows, otherwise above used
    {
        "cmd": ["C:/Program Files/nodejs/node", "$file"]
    }

}
```

This way, if you are symlinked from one OS to another, your build system won't break because it can't find the correct path.